How to set LpPulpVariable into int to get list values enter the objective function
I am trying to implement a PulP optimization problem and I use teo of the 4 optimization variables to be optimized to extract an element from a list. The problem is that the program complains that it's not an instance of int but a LpVarible and therefore doesn't return anything and crashes.
The code is as follows
import pulp

# Create a LP Minimization problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("Optimal_Profit", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Define indices
Dates = range(len(commodity_prices))

# Define variables
deposit_date = pulp.LpVariable("Deposit_Date", lowBound=0, upBound=58, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
withdrawal_date = pulp.LpVariable("Withdrawal_Date", lowBound=0, upBound=58, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
volume_deposit = pulp.LpVariable("Volume_Deposit", lowBound=0, upBound=50, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
volume_withdrawal = pulp.LpVariable("Volume_Withdrawal", lowBound=0, upBound=50, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

deposit_date.setInitialValue(0)
withdrawal_date.setInitialValue(0)
volume_deposit.setInitialValue(0)
volume_withdrawal.setInitialValue(0)

# Define objective function
prob += volume_withdrawal * commodity_prices[(withdrawal_date)] - volume_deposit *      commodity_prices[(deposit_date)] - 0.01 * (withdrawal_date - deposit_date)
# Define constraints
prob += withdrawal_date - deposit_date >= 1
prob += volume_withdrawal - volume_deposit <= 50

# Solve the optimization problem
prob.solve()

# Print results
print("Optimal Deposit Date:", int(deposit_date.value()))
print("Optimal Withdrawal Date:", int(withdrawal_date.value()))
print("Optimal Deposit Volume:", volume_deposit.value())
print("Optimal Withdrawal Volume:", volume_withdrawal.value())
print("Optimal New Variable Value:", new_variable.value())
print("Optimal Profit:", pulp.value(prob.objective))

Assume that rate, costs and total_volume are constants.
Commodity prices is a list containing commodity prices.

Welcome to SO. Can you post the actual error message? My guess is that the problem is you are trying to index into the commodity_prices list using the withdrawal_date which is LpVariable not int.
